# Notification tray icon says I have Windows Updates to install, but I don't

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a notification bar icon informing me I have important updates to install.

[image]

But when I click through, Windows Update tells me I'm up to date

[image]

As you can see by the yellow text, this is a machine on a domain where updates are published through WSUS. Could it be that the tray icon is going off updates available outside of WSUS? I can't clear the notification from the tray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may hide the icon from
*Settings > Personalisation > Taskbar > Select which icons appear on the taskbar*.

Disable "Windows Update Status" to hide the icon.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the 2 are out of sync? Or how to get them back in sync?

Comment: It might be a WSUS bug or admin problem.